# base64 encoding and decoding tool

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, base64

I wanted to understand how base64 encoding (and decoding) works so I implemented this tool in the spirit of "classic UNIX tools" (read from stdin, write to stdout).

I'd like to get general feedback on style and implementation (hoping I got it right). Also, since I'm doing bit manipulation, should I worry about endianness?

`b64.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define USAGE   "usage: b64 [-d]\n" \
                "  base64 encode/decode standard input to standard output\n"

static void     die(const char *reason);
static void     encode(void);
static void     decode(void);
static int      getcharskipn(void);
static int      isvalid(int c);

static char enctable[] =
{
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
        'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b',
        'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
        'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3',
        '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/',
};

static int dectable[] =
{
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 62, -1, -1, -1, 63, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57,
        58, 59, 60, 61, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,
         7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
        25, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36,
        37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        if (argc == 1)
                encode();
        else if (argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0)
                decode();
        else
                die(USAGE);

        return 0;
}

static void die(const char *reason)
{
        fprintf(stderr, reason);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static void encode(void)
{
        int b1, b2, b3;
        unsigned long g;        /* group of 4 6-bit indices for enctable built using 3 input bytes */

        while ((b1 = getchar()) != EOF) {
                b2 = getchar();
                b3 = getchar();

                g = b1;
                g = (g << 8) | (b2 == EOF ? 0 : b2);
                g = (g << 8) | (b3 == EOF ? 0 : b3);

                putchar(enctable[(g >> 18) & 0x3F]);
                putchar(enctable[(g >> 12) & 0x3F]);
                putchar(b2 == EOF ? '=' : enctable[(g >> 6) & 0x3F]);
                putchar(b3 == EOF ? '=' : enctable[g & 0x3F]);
        }
}

static void decode(void)
{
        int c1, c2, c3, c4;
        unsigned long g;        /* group of 3 bytes built using dectable indexed by 4 input characters */

        while ((c1 = getcharskipn()) != EOF) {
                c2 = getcharskipn();
                c3 = getcharskipn();
                c4 = getcharskipn();

                if ( ! isvalid(c1) || c1 == '='
                ||   ! isvalid(c2) || c2 == '='
                ||   ! isvalid(c3)
                ||   ! isvalid(c4))
                        die("b64: invalid input\n");

                g = dectable[c1];
                g = (g << 6) | dectable[c2];
                g = (g << 6) | (c3 == '=' ? 0 : dectable[c3]);
                g = (g << 6) | (c4 == '=' ? 0 : dectable[c4]);

                putchar((g >> 16) & 0xFF);
                if (c3 != '=')
                        putchar((g >> 8) & 0xFF);
                if (c4 != '=')
                        putchar(g & 0xFF);
        }
}

static int getcharskipn(void)
{
        int c;

        if ((c = getchar()) == '\n')
                return getchar();

        if (c == '\r') {
                if ((c = getchar()) == '\n')
                        return getchar();
                ungetc(c, stdin);
                return '\r';
        }

        return c;
}

static int isvalid(int c)
{
        return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            || (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            || c == '+' || c == '/' || c == '=';
}
```

`b64.test`

```sh
#!/bin/sh

test_str()
{
        printf "%s" "$1" > original
        printf "%s" "$2" > expected

        ./b64 < original > enc
        diff enc expected || exit 1

        ./b64 -d < enc > dec
        diff dec original || exit 1
}

test_rnd()
{
        head -c "$1" /dev/urandom > rnd

        ./b64 < rnd > enc
        ./b64 -d < enc > dec
        diff dec rnd || exit 1
}

cleanup()
{
        rm original expected rnd dec enc
}

test_str "" ""
test_str "f" "Zg=="
test_str "fo" "Zm8="
test_str "foo" "Zm9v"
test_str "foob" "Zm9vYg=="
test_str "fooba" "Zm9vYmE="
test_str "foobar" "Zm9vYmFy"
test_str "foobarb" "Zm9vYmFyYg=="
test_str "foobarba" "Zm9vYmFyYmE="
test_str "foobarbaz" "Zm9vYmFyYmF6"
for i in `seq 1000 1024`; do test_rnd $i; done

cleanup
echo "all tests passed"
```

`Makefile`

```
.POSIX:

CC     := cc
CFLAGS := -std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror
PREFIX := /usr/local

all: b64.debug

b64.debug: b64.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -g -DDEBUG $^ -o $@

b64: b64.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DNDEBUG $^ -o $@

test: b64
    sh b64.test

install: b64
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin
    cp b64 $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin

uninstall:
    rm $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin/b64

clean:
    rm -f b64 b64.debug
```

Comment: Looks like you've reimplemented [`uudecode`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uudecode).

Comment: @Edward well I know I've "reinvented the wheel". I did it for learning. There is also [base64](https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64) from GNU and I guess countless many more.

Comment: It was just an observation, not a complaint!  :)

Comment: You may also want to avoid calling exit. Instead return the error And have it bubble up to the main function which will then return EXIT_FAILURE. Otherwise you risk some cleanup procedure not being called. Not that there Is one atm, but you never know how things Will evolve. Its a good practice to have just one exit point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the code looks like you are very experienced since you didn't make any obvious mistakes.

Some small things to consider:

- I'd compile the release binary with assertions enabled since I prefer an obvious crash over undefined behavior.
- Since you don't include `<assert.h>` at all, you don't need the `-DNDEBUG` flags at all since they won't make any difference.
- The headers from the C standard library should be sorted alphabetically.
- The function name `isvalid` is reserved for future versions of the C standard library, though I don't think that name will ever be taken. The name `isvalid` is way too unspecific to land in the standard library. In the narrow scope of a base64 encoder/decoder, the name is perfect.
- Your decision to have 18 table entries per line looks a bit arbitrary to me. I'd select 16 since that's how the code points in ASCII are arranged.
- The decoding table assumes that the execution character set is ASCII. Try running this program on an IBM machine. :)
- Since you already use the `const` keyword, it makes sense to use it for `enctable` and `dectable` as well.
- At the very end of the program, you could check `stdin` and `stdout` for I/O errors and in such a case return `EXIT_FAILURE`.
- Having a test suite with even fuzzing included makes the code trustworthy. :)
- The Makefile even works on ancient Solaris where `/bin/sh` does not even know about functions. In such a situation, one can just set `PATH` before running make and thereby provide a sane shell.
- Thank you for including `DESTDIR` in the Makefile. :)
- For installing the program, you should not use `cp`:

  - It will overwrite the file in-place, which leads to problems if the program is still running while being overwritten.
  - It doesn't overwrite write-protected files. Use `install -m 555 b64 $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin/` instead.

In my mind the program is ready to be used and packaged. You might write a manual page to make the distribution package complete.

Comment: thank you for your feedback! I didn't know about `install`, I definitely going to use it from now on =) To fix the "IBM machine" problem I think I could build `dectable` at runtime starting from `enctable` and maybe make `isvalid` dependent on `dectable` since I suspect that `isvalid` wouldn't work either on non-ascii machine. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Sounds perfect.